# Gson throws exception when expected string array returns object

Tags: json, gson

I'm using an api where a particular field (below) normally contains a string array. However, if the array is empty, the api returns an empty object in what is normally the array of string. Here is the field that's causing problems.

Normal.

```
"a": [
    "str"
    ]
```

Empty.

```
"a": [
    {}
    ]
```

The second case causes Gson to crash with a JsonSyntaxException. How do I handle this?

Comment: So this is a field in some object not the whole object?

Comment: Yes that's right. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way, but it works.

The faulty field can be annotated with @JsonAdapter(MyTypeAdapter.class). The TypeAdapter can then use its read method and check using peek() weather or not the next value is of the expected type.

Comment: This is a great option also did not know about that annotation earlier. It still might be a bit easier to do with `JsonDeserializer`, updated my answer.

Comment: It looks to be that they're about equal in terms of difficulty. Either way I learnt something new. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume you have a class representing the API response, like:

```
public class Response {
    private String[] a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
}
```

One way to get the `Response` object parsed whether JSON for `a` is valid or not is to create a `JsonDeserializer` that checks if `a` can parsed and excludes parsing of `a` if it fails, so leaves `a` to `null`.

```
public class SkipBadSyntaxDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Response> {

    // This strategy is used if parse of field a fails
    private final ExclusionStrategy excludeA = new ExclusionStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
            return "a".equals(f.getName());
        }

        // no need to care of this used only here for the Response class
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    // one parser for good and another for bad format
    private final Gson gson = new Gson(),
            gsonBadFormat = new GsonBuilder()
                    .addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(excludeA).create();;

    @Override
    public Response deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, 
                JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            return gson.fromJson(json, Response.class);
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            // parse a failed try again without it  
            return gsonBadFormat.fromJson(json, Response.class);
        }

    }

}
```

Try it with:

```
new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Response.class,
            new SkipBadSyntaxDeserializer())
                 .create()
                 .fromJson(JSON, Response.class);
```

If JSON would be like:

```
{
    "a": [{}],
    "b": "bval",
    "c": "cval"   
}
```

then properties for `Response` would be:

```
a=null
b="bval"
c="cval"
```

### Update

Based on your own answer: if it is possible to alter DTO for response then using annotation `@JsonAdapter` will let you to handle this per field. Deserializer will then be simply:

```
public class SkipExceptionAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<String[]> {
    @Override
    public String[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            return context.deserialize(json, String[].class);
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return new String[] {}; // or null how you wish
        }
    }
}
```

and annotation in `Response.a`

```
@JsonAdapter(SkipExceptionAdapter.class)
private String[] a;
```

will handle it for that field only.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. Unfortunately it seems that all fields of the problematic type are skipped. I still need to populate the fields that do contain data, not skipping the type alltogether.

Comment: @jami It _should_ skip only the problematic field `a` not all fields.Need to test it again.

Comment: @jami No problem that I could see. Updated `Response` and added what I tested.

Comment: Strange. I was looking at my data and while gson no longer crashes, this field was empty in every case. I'll experiment more tomorrow. Thanks Pirho.